# Add arrays to the numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to add newly created arrays to other numpy array, but I'm doing something wrong. What I want, is to add multiple arrays like `numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])`, to already created array, so I could get something like this:

```
x = numpy.array([])

for i in np.arange(5):
    y = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
    x = np.append(x, y)

result:
x = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

However, with the loop shown above I get this:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = []
for i in range(5):
    y = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
    x.append(y)

x = numpy.array(x)
```

or:

```
N = 5
x = numpy.zeros((N, 4))

for i in range(N):
     x[i] = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Here I avoid `numpy.append` and `numpy.vstack` inside the loop because it can be quite slow. Every call to `numpy.append` or `numpy.vstack` creates an empty array and copies both `x` and `y` into the new empty array. If you use a list to hold the rows of array until the loop is over, the array just gets copied once at the end.

If neither of the above work for you, you could do something like this (but it'll be slower):

```
x = numpy.zeros((0, 4))

for i in range(5):
     y = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
     x = numpy.vstack(x, y)
```

Comment: For what it’s worth,  I believe the last, suboptimal example should read: `for i in range(5):    y = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])    x = numpy.vstack((x, y))`

Answer (score 2):

`append` adds to the end of the array. Since `x` only has one dimension (it has shape `(0,)` to begin with) it can grow only in the way you observe.

It's not generally the right tool to use to build multi-dimensional arrays incrementally as you're doing - you can add append to a specific access (and so stack arrays) but you need to ensure that both arrays are the same shape, and same size along that axis. On top of this the array you're appending to must be copied each time.

A more succinct way to build your required array could be to use `np.tile` instead:

```
>>> np.tile([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (5, 1)) # (5,1) means 5/1 copies along axis 0/1
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```